# Banner ad won't show in main.xml

Tags: android, layout, admob

I've been tearing my hair out all night trying to get this to work. I've done all the background work to display the ad, however it's the banner in the main.xml that I cannot display and I think it's to do with my layouts, however I really do not know where I'm going wrong. I cannot seem to add the banner anywhere on this screen without it moving off the screen in eclipse or making everything else disappear. I know it works because if I take away my vertical layouts the ad displays. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="A" android:id="@+id/buttona" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="E" android:id="@+id/buttone" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="I" android:id="@+id/buttoni" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="M" android:id="@+id/buttonm" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Q" android:id="@+id/buttonq" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="U" android:id="@+id/buttonu" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Y" android:id="@+id/buttony" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="B" android:id="@+id/buttonb" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="F" android:id="@+id/buttonf" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="J" android:id="@+id/buttonj" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="N" android:id="@+id/buttonn" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="R" android:id="@+id/buttonr" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="V" android:id="@+id/buttonv" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Z" android:id="@+id/buttonz" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="C" android:id="@+id/buttonc" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="G" android:id="@+id/buttong" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="K" android:id="@+id/buttonk" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="O" android:id="@+id/buttono" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="S" android:id="@+id/buttons" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="W" android:id="@+id/buttonw" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="D" android:id="@+id/buttond" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="H" android:id="@+id/buttonh" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="L" android:id="@+id/buttonl" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="P" android:id="@+id/buttonp" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="T" android:id="@+id/buttont" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="X" android:id="@+id/buttonx" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="More" android:id="@+id/more" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_marginTop="35dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:textSize="15dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I followed this tutorial and I'm at the point of displaying the ad in the main screen
http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ad is not showing because your button columns have a `layout_height` of `fill_parent`, so there is nowhere for the ad to be displayed on the screen.  To fix this problem, you will probably want to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) as your base layout, [define your ad in XML](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html), set your ad to the bottom of the screen (your preference), and set your entire button LinearLayout to sit ABOVE the AdView, so it has enough space to show.

I would recommend reading about RelativeLayout and defining your ad in XML for more details about how these changes affect your app, but for your convenience, I have also provided an updated version of what your layout would look like with my suggested changes.  Remember to replace the AdUnitId with your own id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="A" android:id="@+id/buttona" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="E" android:id="@+id/buttone" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="I" android:id="@+id/buttoni" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="M" android:id="@+id/buttonm" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Q" android:id="@+id/buttonq" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="U" android:id="@+id/buttonu" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Y" android:id="@+id/buttony" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="B" android:id="@+id/buttonb" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="F" android:id="@+id/buttonf" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="J" android:id="@+id/buttonj" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="N" android:id="@+id/buttonn" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="R" android:id="@+id/buttonr" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="V" android:id="@+id/buttonv" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Z" android:id="@+id/buttonz" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="C" android:id="@+id/buttonc" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="G" android:id="@+id/buttong" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="K" android:id="@+id/buttonk" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="O" android:id="@+id/buttono" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="S" android:id="@+id/buttons" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="W" android:id="@+id/buttonw" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <Button android:text="D" android:id="@+id/buttond" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="H" android:id="@+id/buttonh" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="L" android:id="@+id/buttonl" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="P" android:id="@+id/buttonp" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="T" android:id="@+id/buttont" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="X" android:id="@+id/buttonx" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="More" android:id="@+id/more" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_marginTop="35dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:textSize="15dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
                         android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         ads:adUnitId="YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to correct that Eric, its very good of you. I'll try this when i get home :D

Comment: To add to this, i did have the vertical layouts as wrap_content which did allow space at the bottom, however i just didn't think to use RelativeLayout as my base layout, purely because of a lack of understanding on how they work. I'll certainly do more reading :)

Comment: I think the RelativeLayout gives you a lot more control over how to place your elements, though it does take a while to get used to how it works.  LinearLayout just slaps together views from top to bottom (in your case left to right because you defined it vertical.  But you can't do things like pin the AdView to the bottom of the screen in a LinearLayout.